# Progress bar in notification not updates in Android O

Tags: android, push-notification, progress-bar, android-8.0-oreo

In my android app, using a progress notification, its working in all android versions except android O. In android O, file is getting downloaded but progress bar is not updating neither it shows "Download Complete". Below is my code which is under AsyncTask --

```
private class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void> {
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, null);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading - "+lblTitle.getText())
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doupnowlogo)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                // Configure the notification channel.
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
                mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            else {
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading - "+lblTitle.getText())
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red))
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250})
                        .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 500, 5000)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);
            }

            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading the file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String...params){
            URL url;
            int count;
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0].replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                String pathl="";
                try {
                    File f=new File(storeDir);
                    if(f.exists()){
                        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
                        String pathr=url.getPath();
                        String filename=pathr.substring(pathr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                        pathl=storeDir+"/"+filename;
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(pathl);
                        int lenghtOfFile = con.getContentLength();
                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;
                            // publishing the progress
                            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                            // writing data to output file
                            fos.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        is.close();
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("Error","Not found: "+storeDir);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
            // Displays the progress bar on notification
            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
            // Removes the progress bar
            mBuilder.setProgress(0,0,false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

The full program is working great in other versions, but getting the problem only in android o.

Comment: Anyone facing this error or i am the only one!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may help you, I am showing notifications in my current ongoing project. It shows notifications from 4.1 to latest 8.0 Oreo. Tested on each platform.

---

Here are my class private members :

```
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";
```

---

In the same class i am creating and showing notifications with following code

```
try
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            startForeground(1,new Notification());

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            // notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                    .setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
                    .setContentText("We are ready to help you.");

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
        else
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, WatchMan.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"mychannel");

            b.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                    .setTicker("Success")
                    .setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
                    .setContentText("We are ready to help you.")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setContentInfo("Info");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Null pointer exception xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...\n");
        System.out.println("Null Pointer ");
    }
```

---

JUST DO NOT USE `startForeground(1,new Notification());` , As i am in service and want to continue onstartcommand to get started.

---

You may see the developer warning TOAST message on android 8.0 oreo and if you or any other member can resolve this issue too then it would be great for both of us.

Comment: It also creates sound() exception on which we can do nothing. You will find many members having same issue. It may be resolved by google in coming oreo versions

Comment: ya tried, same issue, progress bar never completes in android O

Answer (score 0):

The problem in line:

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, null);
```

You should use channel_id in builder constructor (you have added it below like `notificationChannel`) Also I see you created channel bellow like:

```
notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
```

I think it's better to use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` for progress notifications because `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` will displays with pops up effect.

So I think the best way to use two channels here. First one for starting/completed/error notifications and second one only for progress. And the first channel will use `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` or `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` priority but progress channel -`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW`. In this implementation we could see start notification with sound vibration etc. and progress notifications without sound in system tray.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);


        //add this
        if(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])==100) {
            new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
             }
             },1000);
        }

        // Displays the progress bar on notification
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

`Sometimes the system ignores the notifications due to the speed of the update`