# Progressbar issue in postexecute() Async Class

Tags: android

i am displaying a progressbar in notification to users when they are downloading something from the app, everything is working the only issue is after download is finished the program enters the onPostExecute() function but the progressbar is not getting removed, i tested it using Log.d() to track. Any idea -

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

                // Configure the notification channel.
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading - "+title)
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doupnowlogo)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setProgress(100, 0, false)
                        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                mBuilderOld = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, null);
                mBuilderOld.setContentTitle("Downloading - "+title)
                        .setContentText("Download in progress")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.doupnowlogo)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                        .setProgress(100, 0, false)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                mNotifyManager.notify(2, mBuilderOld.build());
            }

            //Toast.makeText(context, "Downloading file...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
                // Displays the progress bar on notification
                mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                mBuilderOld.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
                // Displays the progress bar on notification
                mNotifyManager.notify(2, mBuilderOld.build());
            }
            Log.d("Progress","I am here");
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        }

protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            super.onProgressUpdate(100);
            Log.d("Progress","I am done");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete");
                // Removes the progress bar
                mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }
            else
            {
                mBuilderOld.setContentText("Download complete");
                // Removes the progress bar
                mBuilderOld.setProgress(0, 0, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(2, mBuilderOld.build());
            }
   }
```

Comment: what's mBuilder and how does it look like?

Comment: @EarlOfEgo..........edit the question, now u can get the idea

Comment: why do you call super.onProgressUpdate(100); in onPostExecute? Try the code without that function call

Comment: @sgrig..........that i added just now, without adding also it was not working

Comment: Notification shows "Download complete" with a progressbar?

Comment: Download Complete not displaying

Comment: It seems there is a bug with updating notification in Android O version.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922806/progress-bar-in-notification-not-updates-in-android-o